# Windows Server 2019 - Disk size not maching the diskpart info

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, windows-server-2019, diskpart

we'd like to get your opinion on this weird issue:

Environment

- Windows Server 2019 VM running on top of an ESXi 7.1 Cluster
- The storage subsystem is a compellent iSCSI array. The other windows VM are not affected by the same issue described below

Issue Description:

- We've increased the size of the VM Hard Drive from 24 TB to 25 TB - The Drive is the "D:" Drive.
- Under the disk management we were able to see the 1TB of free space, so we've decided to expand the NTFS just a little bit ( 500 GB more )
- According disk part, we see:

[DiskPart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ7vy.png)

- According windows explorer we see:

[Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsNYD.png)

- We've also decided to install a 3rd party software to check if there was some kind of misconfiguration... currently we're using EaseUS, it shows the correct NTFS Size:

[EaseUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s1DX.png)

Do you know how to fix that please ? it looks like the new space hasn't been allocated.

Comment: It's not clear to me, did you extend the Windows volume after increasing the size of the VMDK?

Comment: Hello Joeqwerty, yes exactly.  We've extended the windows volume after increasing the size of the vmdk.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me in the past to reconcile the different sizes for my drives size showing in disk management and windows explorer disk properties:

```
C\ > DISKPART
DISKPART> List Volume
DISKPART> select volume # (this is the number of the volume listed by the above ‘List Volume’ command)
DISKPART> extend filesystem
DISKPART> exit
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I did it right now. Unfortunately nothing is changed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wqHe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtchh.png)

Do you have any other advice for us ?